# Setting size of JPanel using MiGLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, miglayout

I'm using the MiGLayout to create several different JPanels, however I'm having a problem resizing one of them. Below is a diagram showing what I want to achieve:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|                                                     |
|                        Panel 1                      |
|                                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------- ---------------------------
|                         | |                         |
|         Panel 2         | |          Panel 3        |
|                         | |                         |
--------------------------- ---------------------------
```

The key thing I want to achieve is to make Panel 1 spread across the two other panels. I seem to have achieved this layout, however I've got an issue such that the border isn't showing up for Panel 1 as shown in my diagram. I have tried using the `setSize` method but it didn't seem to work.

Here is the code I'm using to create the panels (please note I haven't included the widgets inside the panel):

```
    // Create Panel 1
    JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();
    panelone.setSize(600, 50);
    panelOne.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel 1"));
    panelOne.setLayout(new MigLayout());

    // Create Panel 2
    JPanel panelTwo = new JPanel();
    panelTwo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel 2"));
    panelTwo.setLayout(new MigLayout());

    // Create Panel 3
    JPanel panelThree = new JPanel();
    panelThree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel 3"));
    panelThree.setLayout(new MigLayout());

    // Add the panels to the main frame
    mainFrame.add(panelOne, "span, wrap, align center");
    mainFrame.add.add(panelTwo);
    mainFrame.add.add(panelThree);
```

Please can someone suggest a way to get the border to be shown as in my diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout());
getContentPane().add(panelTwo);
getContentPane().add(panelThree,  "wrap");   // Wrap to next row
getContentPane().add(panelOne, "dock north");
```

Also, ensure you are adding your GUI elements to the main frame's content pane not to the frame itself.

**EDIT** From the comments below:
You can also use `new CC.wrap()` or `new CC.dockNorth()`
**Thanks to @Andrew Thompson and @Howard for the tip :)**

Comment: @Andrew Thompson You can use `new CC().wrap()` or `new CC().dockNorth()`.

Comment: @Howard  Thanks for the heads-up.   If the OA (original answerer, e.g. GETah) could edit that into their question, that will score an up-vote here.

Answer (score 4):

```
panelone.setSize(600, 50);  // from original code
```

I've never used that layout, but layouts in general are more likely to respect (enforce) the preferred size than the size.

Comment: Forcing the size won't really help will it? What if the main container's size changes?

Comment: @GETah A 'preferred size' does not 'force' anything.  do you understand the meaning of 'preferred'?  (Sorry, that is not intended to sound as insulting as it probably is - it is just that I'm never sure of a person's familiarity with English in these multi-national forums.)

Comment: No problem, I know very well what preferred means :) Your answer refers to setting the size not the preferred size :)

Comment: @GETah  My answer simply quotes the line of the original code that I wanted to contest.  ;)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I suggest you add a line next to it to make sure future readers won't misunderstand your answer as I did :)

Comment: I used `setMinimumSize()` instead and it worked well.